# Error after removing column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I removed a column named assignment from my assignments database and encountered the following error:

[image]

assignments_controller.rb:

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /assignments
    # GET /assignments.json
    def index
        @assignments = Assignment.all
    end

    def mylist
        @assignments = Assignment.where(user_id: current_user.id).find_each
    end

    # def bidders
    #     @bids = Bid.where(bidders_params).find_each
    #     #@bidders = User.where(user.id => @bids.user_id).find_each
    #     @bids.each do |bid|
    #         @bidders = User.where(user.id => bid.user_id).find_each
    #     end
    # end

    # def bidders
    #     idders_ids = Bid.where(bidders_params).pluck(:user_id)
    #     @bidders = User.where(id: bidders_ids)
    # end

    # GET /assignments/1
    # GET /assignments/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /assignments/new
    def new
        @assignment = Assignment.new
    end

    # GET /assignments/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /assignments
    # POST /assignments.json
    def create
        @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @assignment.save
                format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /assignments/1
    # PATCH/PUT /assignments/1.json
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @assignment.update(assignment_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @assignment }
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /assignments/1
    # DELETE /assignments/1.json
    def destroy
        @assignment.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: 'Assignment was successfully destroyed.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
        @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def assignment_params
        params.require(:assignment).permit(:education_id, :subject_id, :gender_prefer, :timeslot, :duration, :budget, :budget_unit, :assignment_info, :user_id, :region_id)
    end

    def bidders_params
        params.permit(:assignment_id)
    end
end
```

I'm well aware that it could be because of the `.require(:assignment)` in:

```
params.require(:assignment).permit(:education_id, :subject_id, :gender_prefer, :timeslot, :duration, :budget, :budget_unit, :assignment_info, :user_id, :region_id)
```

I've tried changing that line to:

```
params.permit(:education_id, :subject_id, :gender_prefer, :timeslot, :duration, :budget, :budget_unit, :assignment_info, :user_id, :region_id)
```

but to no avail.

Please help me on this matter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you need to just restart your server, your code look perfect.

Comment: Can you check your model and make sure you remove all methods that were related to column ```assignment```

Comment: Can we see the model;